# Создать папку, а в ней файл и положить в него какой-то текст

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

Написал код, который бы генерировал мне различные папки. Предполагается, что код будет создавать папку, а внутри неё файл. Затем, открывать файл и записывать в него контент:

```
filename = airline["iata"] + '/index.php'
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
    os.makedirs(filename)
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write("<?php include('generator.php'); ?>")
```

В итоге должна получиться папка `AA/index.php`, но вместо создания файла у меня создаётся вложенная папка с названием `index.php`. Как мне сделать так, чтобы создавался файл в только что созданной папке и записать в него контент?

Comment: Вы передаете `filename` в `makedirs`- здесь и происходит создание папки `index.php`, так как вы передаете название с расширением.

Answer (score 2):

В `makedirs` нужно передавать папку:

```
filename = airline["iata"] + '/index.php'
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
    dir_name = os.path.dirname(filename)
    os.makedirs(dir_name)

    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write("<?php include('generator.php'); ?>")
```